# SAPUI5 sap.m.List: Divider

Tags: list, menu, grouping, sapui5, divider

I have a menu for my mobile app that displays various actions. These actions can be grouped and I would like to separate these groups by a divider. Unfortunately, there is no such divider. How would you solve this issue? By css? Or by creating a custom list item? How would this look like?

Any good ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a mobile app, I'm assuming you're using a List control from the sap.m library.

You could use the List control's grouping facilities to have custom group 'subheaders' amongst your items. They look like dividers. You don't need to create any custom CSS.

To see how this would look, and how to do it, have a look at the [List - Grouping sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrouping/preview) in the UI5 Explored app.

For more information on custom sorting and grouping in a List, you might find this post of mine useful too: "[Custom Sorting and Grouping](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/11/29/custom-sorter-and-grouper)".

Comment: @qmarco: Do you have a Link to that Custom Sorting and Grouping post?

Comment: @qmarco: Yes, a link would be great as I am hoping to get more exmaples there. I am building the list manually and I do not want to create a nested model first to be able to set a sorter with grouping enabled....

Comment: @qmarco, good one, please see the link http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/11/29/custom-sorter-and-grouper

Comment: I've added the link to the answer, sorry about that, I don't know what happened while I was adding it 1st time around.

BTW - it's qmacro, not qmarco :)

Comment: @qmacro: So there is no way to insert them as items? I need to do the workaround and use a model??   :-(

Answer (score 0):

OK, according to qmarco's suggestion, I created a custom control derived from the sap.m.StandardListItem and assigned the same style classes as SAPUI5 does for the group header list items - et voilà:

```
sap.m.StandardListItem.extend("controls.CustomListDivider", {

init: function() {
    sap.m.StandardListItem.prototype.init.call(this);
    this.setType(sap.m.ListType.Inactive);
},

renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
    oRm.addClass("myListDivider");

    // add style classes from Group Header List Item
    oRm.addClass("sapMGHLI");
    oRm.addClass("sapMGHLIUpperCase");
    oRm.addClass("sapMLIB");
    oRm.addClass("sapMLIB-CTX");
    oRm.addClass("sapMLIBShowSeparator");
    oRm.addClass("sapMLIBTypeInactive");

    sap.m.StandardListItemRenderer.render(oRm, oControl);
}
```

Now you can manually add it to your list without the need of using a model or sorter etc.